# Structured referencing: sum cells at intersection of current row and some columns

Tags: excel

I am using structured tables in Excel 2010.

In table "P" I have multiple columns labeled 1a, 1b, 1c, 2a, 2b, 3a ...
The data are some numeric values.

In table "Q" I would like to have columns labeled 1, 2, 3 and each colum should have a sum of the values of table "P" in the corresponding group of columns. That is:

- Column 1 should sum up the contents in columns labeled 1a, 1b, 1c
- Column 2 should sum up 2a, 2b
- Column 3 should sum up 3a, ...

All this should be done on per-row basis.

---

As a start, I was trying to actually do something simpler and reference a single cell in the current row. By reading the [documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-HA010342999.aspx) I tried the following:

```
=P[[#This Row],[1a]]
```

but even this is causing some formula error which I don't understand.

---

Update:

With SUMIF I managed to get very close to what I want:

```
=SUMIF(P[#Headers]; "1a"; P[@])
```

and if I could somehow grab the tested header value and plug it into the `SEARCH` function - I would be able to accomplish what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(P[#Headers],P[#Headers]-1)="1")*P)
```

`(LEFT(P[#Headers],P[#Headers]-1)="1")` will return an array which will say what headers in table P has `1` as the first integer. This will then be used to determine which columns in the table to sum up.

`LEFT(P[#Headers],P[#Headers]-1)` returns the integer from your headers. It basically removes the last character from each header and compares it to `1` in the above case.

Comment: @CygnusX1 What are the possible header names in table P?

Comment: @CygnusX1 Is there a maximum length of any of the two? Only one character for instance?

Comment: Character is a character. Not a string of characters. Integer is going to be "reasonable". It probably won't reach 100, although in theory it could. No negatives either.

Comment: @CygnusX1 Fixed the formula to cater for that.